# "Uncaught Reference Error: Polymer is not defined" caused by IP-change?

Tags: yeoman, polymer, bower

so I didn't touch my current project for almost one month and after that, nothing is running anymore and I get the message

```
Uncaught Reference Error: Polymer is not defined
```

for each of my Polymer-Elements and this one once:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     http://localhost:9000/bower_components/tools/loader/loader.js
 Uncaught ReferenceError: PolymerLoader is not defined
```

I have Polymer included in my main html-file like this:
`<script src="bower_components/polymer/polymer.js"></script>`

I already deleted and reinstalled all my bower_components, downloaded Polymer directly from GitHub and added the PolymerLoader manually to the referenced directory(deleted it again after it did not work). 
I am unsing Version 0.0.20131010 of Polymer (I know it's very old, but it used to work before...) and the newest version of Bower.
I can't find an explanation for all this.

The only thing that has changed is the IP-address of the computer, which I am not refering to anywhere in my code.

I hope you could share some of your thoughts on this with me.

Comment: Two things I forgot to mention: I get this error with every project that includes Polymer! And I originally got a different message since I included Polymer via ``<script src="bower_components/polymer/polymer.min.js"></script>``, I got a 404 error, because there was no polymer.min.js.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I also worked with Polymer a few months ago and now that I resumed, I get the same error you mention (Uncaught Reference Error: Polymer is not defined).

Comment: @jorgeh I solved the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483374/404-not-found-for-polymer-min-js

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong / misconfigured with the HTTP server that's serving these files out. It's not a polymer error if you're getting a 404 for the .js files.

Please ask a new question and include information about the tools that you're using to serve out HTTP.